# Dojo Datagrid keep scrolling up on Chrome

Tags: datagrid, dojo, scroll

How do I fix this issue where whenever there is a vertical scrollbar on the datagrid and I scroll down, it magically scrolls up automatically till the top. This happens in Chrome but theres no problem in Firefox. I am currently using Dojo 1.6 for this

Comment: Even at build.dojotoolkit.org there's the automatic scroll up on my browser, using the latest Chromium build on Ubuntu. Really obnoxious as "new" content isn't loaded as you scroll down.